# has_and_belongs_to_many associations in factory_girl 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm new to factory_girl and trying to figure out how to effectively generate a factory for the following models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tags < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :companies

    validates :type , :inclusion => { :in => %w(market location) } 
end
```

I've taken a look at previous answers on StackOverflow (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484374/how-to-create-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations-in-factory-girl)), however most of them are outdated and/or don't have a proper answer to the question.  Is there anybody out there that can help define factories for these two objects with Factorygirl?

**Update**

Here's what I've come up wtih so far

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :tag do
    id  448
        trait :market do
        type "market"
    end
    trait :location do
        type "location"
    end
    name "software"
end

factory :company do
    id  1234
    name "Apple Inc."
    factory :company_with_tags do
        #setting the default # of tags for companies
        ignore do
            tag_count   2
        end

            after(:create) do |company , evaluator|
                FactoryGirl.create_list(:tag , evaluator.tag_count , company: company)
            end 
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Does this question help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484374/how-to-create-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations-in-factory-girl?rq=1

Comment: The top answer doesn't actually answer the question ... the second one comes close but appears outdated.

Comment: i'm having the same issue here with factory for user and roles (where i have an habtm relationship between the 2. Have you found a solution yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the association name is specified incorrectly. A `Tag` has many companies, not one, so:

```
after(:create) do |company , evaluator|
  FactoryGirl.create_list(:tag , evaluator.tag_count , companies: [company])
end
```

As a side note, you want to avoid using `type` as a column name, unless you are trying to set up a polymorphic relationship.

Comment: and what would be the factory for the tag ?