# Undefined method after_create with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to defined a has_many relationship in FactoryGirl using the after_create callback, like so in /spec/factories/emails.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :email do
        after_create do |email|
            email.attachments << FactoryGirl.build(:attachment)
        end
    end
end
```

The attachment is defined in a seperate factory /spec/factories/attachment.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :attachment do
        # Attach the file to paperclip
        file { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', 'myimage.png'), 'image/png') }
    end
end
```

Using the :attachment in my specs works absolutely fine, so I'm confident that the factory for that is not the problem, however when I try and create an :email from the factory I get the following exception thrown:

```
Failure/Error: email = FactoryGirl.create(:email)
    NoMethodError:
        undefined method `after_create=' for #<Email:0x007ff0943eb8e0>
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do, can't seem to find any one else getting the same error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

FactoryGirl [recently changed](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/23039827914/get-your-callbacks-on-with-factory-girl-3-3) the syntax for callbacks. I think the following will work:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :email do
    after(:create) do |email|
      email.attachments << FactoryGirl.build(:attachment)
    end
  end
end
```