# FactoryGirl circular dependency and validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec

I'm new with FactoryGirl, in Ruby, I'm trying to write some rspec but I got some troubles with a circular dependency. I searched and tried several things, the last one generated an infinite loop and I had to shutdown my WM. (proc 100%)

**models/Vote**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vote_options
```

**models/vote_option**

```
class VoteOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vote
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vote_options, reject_if: :all_blank
```

**spec/models/vote_spec**

```
describe Vote do
  describe 'should return the good label' do
    let(:nobody) { FactoryGirl.create(:vote, visibility: 0) }
    it "should not be visible" do
      nobody.intercom_custom_data[:visibility].should == I18n.t("votes.new.visibility_none")
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/factories**

```
factory :vote do
    team
    question 'Question?'
    question_type 0

    # Avoid validation because of the circular dependency.
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322353/factory-girl-create-that-bypasses-my-model-validation
    after(:build) do |vote|
      vote.vote_options << VoteOption.create(vote_id: vote.id)
      #vote.save!(:validate => false)
    end
  end

  factory :vote_allowed do
    user
    vote
    allowed 1
  end

  factory :vote_casted do
    vote_allowed
    vote_options
  end

  factory :vote_options do
    vote
    title 'default option'
  end
```

This is the code which did an infinite loop. I guess that it created vote and vote_options infinitely because of the circular dependency.

So, I got a vote which have many vote_options (the user choices), each vote_options contains its parent id. The validation reject the creation if fields are blank, we don't have problems with this code to save a new vote/vote_options because everything is done in the same transaction.

But, with the rspec, I can't create at the same time the vote and a vote_options rows depending of each other. (Or I don't know how to do it)

So, I tried to avoid the validation like this:

```
after(:create) do |vote|
  VoteOption.create(vote_id: vote.id)
  vote.save!(:validate => false)
end
```

But I got an error:

```
Failure/Error: let(:nobody) { FactoryGirl.create(:vote, visibility: 0) }
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Vote options can't be blank
```

I tried to use `after_create` instead of `after(:create)` before but my FactoryGirl is in 4.3, so after_create doesn't exists anymore. I found a tutorial about "how use after_create in >3.3" at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003968/undefined-method-after-create-with-factorygirl but it doesn't works for me, I should not get the "vote options can't be blank"... So I took a look at the doc linked in the previous link and I tried to add in **spec/factories**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  after(:create) {|instance| instance.create }
```

But I don't really understand what I should do and I don't understand where is the problem. Any idea?

**Edit #1:**

```
factory :vote do
    team
    question 'Question?'
    question_type 0

    association :vote_options, factory: :vote_options
    # tried with :create and :build
    after(:create) do |vote, evaluator|
      create_list(:vote_options, 1, vote: vote)
    end
  end
```

Comment: What does one your specs that triggers this problem look like?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand clearly the question. I don't have trouble in other specs. The issue here is because of the way the models are designed, with a circular dependency and because the validation refuses to create new instances if the fields are blank, so I need to avoid the validation. I did it with the `vote.save!(:validate => false)` and it seemed to work because I did't get the blank fields" but I got the "after_create is not  function" instead, so I used "after(:create)" but I got again the "blank fields" so I don't know what doesn't works here.

Comment: why don't you use *factorygirl* associations?

Comment: @majioa What do you meant? As I said, I'm new with FactoryGirl/Ruby, I work on an big existing project and I'm trying to figure out many things, I don't know anything about associations in FactoryGirl.

Comment: I meant chapter association: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: You have to use associations and lists

Comment: I tried to use associations and list but I still get the error:
NameError:
       uninitialized constant VoteOptions

The point is that I define :vote_options after :vote, but if I do it before I just move the problem because :vote_options will need :vote to be defined before too...

Comment: use `VoteOption` instead of `VoteOptions`, i.e. `:vote_option`

Comment: I don't use neither VoteOptions or VoteOption in the vote_spec or factories. We made a change about that in a config file, where we define "exceptions".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do according the *Association* chapter of the [document](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)?

```
ignore do
   vote_options_count = 1
end

after(:build) do | vote, evaluator |
   create_list( :vote_option, evaluator.vote_options_count, vote: vote )
end
```

After that it should be allowed to access as follows:

```
create(:vote).vote_options.length # 0
create(:vote, vote_options_count: 15).vote_options.length # 15
```

**NOTE**: The `vote_option` factory must be defined as of a single, not a plural case.

Comment: But I can't define vote_options before, it also need vote to be defined... ^^'

Comment: @Vadorequest why can't you shell to define `vote_option` - single, not plural?

Comment: Maybe you're right, so in the factories.rb I changed vote_options to vote_option but I got: Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep

Comment: @Vadorequest Begin with simple factory `vote`, and `vote_option` without any associations, or assignment. Try to create at first `:vote_option`, then `:vote`, then add association to `:vote`, and chack again.

Comment: It will fails, I have DB and model constraints, I need to pass the validation.

Comment: @Vadorequest disable the constrains and validation, since the DB will always dropped to empty after the tests, then you have got the test passed, enable them one-by-one

Answer (score 0):

I did like tat:

**spec/factories**

```
factory :vote_option do
    vote
    title 'default option'
  end

  factory :vote do
    team
    question 'Question?'
    question_type 0
    vote_options_attributes {[{
      title: 'foo'
    }]}
  end

  factory :vote_allowed do
    user
    vote
    allowed 1
  end

  factory :vote_casted do
    vote_allowed
    vote_option
  end
```

**spec/models/vote_spec**

```
describe Vote do

  describe 'should return the good label' do
    let(:nobody) { FactoryGirl.create(:vote, visibility: 0) }

    it "should not be visible" do
      #nobody.intercom_custom_data[:visibility].should == I18n.t("votes.new.visibility_none")
      puts nobody.inspect
      puts nobody.vote_options.inspect
    end

  end
end
```

*Console*:

```
Run options: exclude {:semaphore_ignore=>true}
#<Vote id: 1, users_id: nil, teams_id: 1, datetime: "2014-01-21 13:42:37", question: "Question?", question_type: 0, not_vote: 0, hidden: nil, visibility: 0>
[#<VoteOption id: 1, vote_id: 1, title: "foo", votes: 0, created_at: "2014-01-21 12:42:37", updated_at: "2014-01-21 12:42:37">]
```

I don't use any association, any list, I just forced to add options_attributes to create automatically vote_options when the vote is created. (Like we do when we create a new vote from the browser)

Thank you majioa.