# Using factory girl to create HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I've been trying now for hours to get factorygirl to create two factories - one for users, one for organizations.

But I don't seem to understand how I can reflect a 'has_and_belongs_to_many' relationship in factories, as soon as I try to create an organization and associate it with an admin user, I run into various error messages (depending on the approach I use). 
My model seems to be working fine, my seed file populates the dev DB and all the associations are created.

Right now my files look like this:

**user factory**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
    after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:user)}

    factory :owner do
      after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:owner)}
    end

    factory :admin do
      after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:admin)}
    end

    factory :superadmin do
      after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:superadmin)}
    end
  end
end
```

**Organization factory**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :organization do |f|
    f.name "example"
    f.website "www.aquarterit.com"
    f.association :users, :factory => :admin
  end
end
```

in my specs I test this:

```
describe Organization do


  it "has a valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:organization).should be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a name" do
    FactoryGirl.build(:organization, name: nil).should_not be_valid
  end

  it "is associated with at least one admin user" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:organization)
    it { should have_and_belong_to_many(:users)}
  end

end
```

all three tests are failing, here are the error message:

```
1) Organization has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:organization).should be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each' for #<User:0x007fadbefda688>
     # ./spec/models/organization_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Organization is invalid without a name
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.build(:organization, name: nil).should_not be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each' for #<User:0x007fadc29406c0>
     # ./spec/models/organization_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Organization is associated with at least one admin user
     Failure/Error: organization = FactoryGirl.create(:organization)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each' for #<User:0x007fadc2a3bf20>
     # ./spec/models/organization_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any help is as always very much appreciated!

**Update**

In theory the same thing that works for assigning roles to the user should work for assigning an admin to the organization. But if I change organizations.rb to

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :organization do
    name "example"
    website "www.aquarterit.com"
    after(:create) {|organization| organization.add_user(:admin)}
  end
end
```

I get following error (I do have gem shoulda installed):

```
1) Organization is associated with at least one admin user
     Failure/Error: it { should have_and_belong_to_many(:users)}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `it' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007ff2395f9000>
     # ./spec/models/organization_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: I think this post answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484374/how-to-create-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations-in-factory-girl

Comment: Thanks - I found that one before, but as far as I understand it's not using the latest syntax; factorygirl now recommends using `after(:create)` to add an association, doesn't it? Updated the original question to include an amended organization factory

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like you are not assigning `users` correctly and not creating the `:admin` user properly.  For this to work, you need to assign an array of users to `organization.users`.  And, you need to populate that array with a `User` instance (this assumes you have a `User` factory named `:admin`).

```
factory :organization do
  name "example"
  website "www.aquarterit.com"
  after(:create) {|organization| organization.users = [create(:admin)]}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way, questions and tests have a HABTM relationship so:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question do
   question  'Some stupid question'
   user nil
   factory :question_with_test do
     # factory_girl's dynamic attributes, ignore it and pass it to evaluator
     transient do
       test nil
     end

     after(:create) do |question, evaluator|
       create(:question_tests, question: question, test: evaluator.test)
     end
   end
  end
end
```

Now I can create a question with HABTM to the Test model:

```
let(:test)             { FactoryGirl.create :test, user: user }
let(:question_test_1)  { FactoryGirl.create :question_with_test, user: user, test: test }
```

The question_tests factory is very basic:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question_tests, class: 'QuestionTest' do
    question
    test
  end
end
```