# Create HABTM relationship in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have the following:

```
    class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :users
      has_many :permissions
      has_one :city
    end


    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :permissions, dependent: :destroy
      has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
    end

    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :user do
        username            { FFaker::Name.first_name }
        email               { FFaker::Internet.email }
        first_name          { FFaker::Name.first_name }
        last_name           { FFaker::Name.last_name }
        current_login_ip "127.0.0.1"
        login_count         { rand(100) + 1 }
        deleted_at nil
        updated_at          { FactoryGirl.generate(:time) }
        created_at          { FactoryGirl.generate(:time) }
        suspended_at nil
        password "password"
        password_confirmation "password"
        vertical {1}
        marketplace_role {1}
      end

      factory :admin do
        admin true
      end


      factory :group do
        users { |a| [a.association(:user)] }
        name                { FFaker::Company.name }
        city                { FactoryGirl.create(:city) }
      end
    end

    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :permission do
        user
        group
        asset               { fail "Please specify :asset for the permission" }
        updated_at          { FactoryGirl.generate(:time) }
        created_at          { FactoryGirl.generate(:time) }
      end
    end

 factory :city do
    name              { FFaker::Name.name }
  end

  factory :zone do
    city
    name              { FFaker::Name.name }
  end

  factory :location do
    zone
    name              { FFaker::Name.name }
  end
```

> Failure/Error: @group = FactoryGirl.create(:group)
>   ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute
>   group_id

This is what I get. I am unable to define and use the groups factory. I looked into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10212304/2015562), But the solution doesnt work.

Comment: please show the `city` factory

Comment: added city factory as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change city factory to the following

```
 factory :city do
    group             nil # or group_id if you will
    name              { FFaker::Name.name }
  end
```

and you'll most likely be good.

Comment: I am getting  undefined method `group=' for #<City id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>. city doesnt belong to group although group has one city.

Comment: it is because you should add `group_id` to `cities` table, otherwise how would it belong _to group? :)

Comment: Group seems to have city_id, not the other way around.

Comment: then group should belong to city, and city has_one :group - you mixed up associations a bit :)